# Python Markdown with footnotes

Tags: python, markdown

I'm not getting what I expected from Python Markdown's footnotes extension.

```
import markdown

content = "Footnotes[^1] have a label[^@#$%] and the footnote's content.\
           \
           [^1]: This is a footnote content.\
           [^@#$%]: A footnote on the label: @#$%."


htmlmarkdown=markdown.markdown( content, extensions=['footnotes'] )
print htmlmarkdown
```

The result is:

```
<p>Footnotes[^1] have a label[^@#$%] and the footnote's content.[^1]: This is a footnote content.[^@#$%]: A footnote on the label: @#$%.</p>
```

The footnotes are not parsed at all! Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no newlines in your lines. The `\` at the end of the lines merely allows you to put your string across multiple lines, it doesn't actually include newline characters. If you *were* to explicitly include newlines, you'd have too much whitespace at the start of your lines and you end up with a `<pre>` block instead.

The following, using triple-quotes to preserve newlines works:

```
>>> import markdown
>>> content = '''\
... Footnotes[^1] have a label[^@#$%] and the footnote's content.
... 
... [^1]: This is a footnote content.
... [^@#$%]: A footnote on the label: @#$%.
... '''
>>> print markdown.markdown( content, extensions=['footnotes'] )
<p>Footnotes<sup id="fnref:1"><a class="footnote-ref" href="#fn:1" rel="footnote">1</a></sup> have a label<sup id="fnref:@#$%"><a class="footnote-ref" href="#fn:@#$%" rel="footnote">2</a></sup> and the footnote's content.</p>
<div class="footnote">
<hr />
<ol>
<li id="fn:1">
<p>This is a footnote content.&#160;<a class="footnote-backref" href="#fnref:1" rev="footnote" title="Jump back to footnote 1 in the text">&#8617;</a></p>
</li>
<li id="fn:@#$%">
<p>A footnote on the label: @#$%.&#160;<a class="footnote-backref" href="#fnref:@#$%" rev="footnote" title="Jump back to footnote 2 in the text">&#8617;</a></p>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
```